# ASP.NET Web Services (plural) or Web Service with multiple classes

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am struggling to make a decision regarding the correct organisation for a web service. Should I have multiple ASMX's representing the different functionality in the web service, or should I have a single ASMX?

If I have multiple ASMX's, does this not constitute multiple web services?

If I have a single ASMX, how do I organise my code (currently my ASMX represents a single class)?

Thanks for any advise!
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend multiple .asmx's mapping to different functional aspects of your app, otherwise you're going to end up with a whopper of an end point. Far too often I see a single endpoint with about 50 web service methods, it's nasty on the end user's dev to have to work with that.

Kev

Answer (score 0):

A way solve the problem of multiple asmx described in the original question.

Read this http://www.freddes.se/2009/02/16/multiple-web-service-references-sharing-types/

and get to know wsdl.exe it is your friend when using .net2 webservices.